# Extract JSON object from each file add it to the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have 4 links, each of them containing one, distinct JSON object. I want to fetch and then place all of them inside of the empty array.
I came up with this(I omited async/await):

```
let arr = [];
let iter = 0;
const FIXED_QUANTITY = 4;
while(iter < FIXED_QUANTITY) {
  const res = axios.get(`/data/${iter}.json`);
  arr = [...arr, res.data.body];
  iter++;
}
```

And my question is - is it possible to make this code a bit more elegant, perhaps using higher order functions?

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this maybe?

```
const urls = [];
const FIXED_QUANTITY = 4;
const iter = 4;

while (iter < FIXED_QUANTITY) {
  urls.push(`/data/${iter}.json`);
}

const arr = await Promise.all([...urls.map(url => axios.get(url))]).map(
  res => res.data.body
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `Array.from` as follow:

```
let arr = Array.from({length: FIXED_QUANTITY}, async (_, iter) => (await axios.get(`/data/${iter}.json`)).data.body);
```

This approach generates an array with the following structure:

```
[{}, {}, ..., {}]
```